# DB Cursor results always empty if I try to get the data with a selective query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a precompiled database and I want to get the data according the passed parameters

But for some strange reason the cursor results always empty

My getData method in the adapter is

```
    public Cursor getData(String uso, String eta, String category,
            String class) {
        try {
            Cursor c;
            if (class.equals(null) && category.equals(null)) {
                c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE Uso LIKE \""
                        + uso + "\" AND Eta LIKE \"" + eta
                        + "\" AND Language LIKE \"" + language
                        + "\" order by Name asc", null);
            } else if (class.equals(null)) {
                c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE Uso LIKE \""
                        + uso + "\" AND Eta LIKE \"" + eta
                        + "\" AND Tipo LIKE \"" + category
                        + "\" AND Language LIKE \"" + language
                        + "\" order by Name asc", null);
            } else if (category.equals(null)) {
                c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE Uso LIKE \""
                        + uso + "\" AND Eta LIKE \"" + eta
                        + "\" AND Certification LIKE \"" + class
                        + "\" AND Language LIKE \"" + language
                        + "\" order by Name asc", null);
            } else {
                c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE Uso LIKE \""
                        + uso + "\" AND Eta LIKE \"" + eta
                        + "\" AND Tipo LIKE \"" + category
                        + "\" AND Certification LIKE \"" + class
                        + "\" AND Language LIKE \"" + language
                        + "\" order by Name asc", null);
            }
            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToNext();
            }
            return c;
        } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getDataCar >>" + mSQLException.toString());
            throw mSQLException;
        }

    } 
...
```

This cursor is used in a method that puts all entries in an array of Car objects

```
public Car[] getDataDBCarsArray(String uso, String eta,
            String category, String class) {
        ArrayList<Car> list = new ArrayList<Car>();
        Cursor c = getData(uso, eta, category, class);
        try {
.....
```

All works fine If instead of the above getData(....) I try to use

```
public Cursor getAllData(){
    try {
        Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM dbtable order by Name asc", null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        return c;
    }catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
        throw mSQLException;
    }

}
```

so seems a problem with the query in getData(...).

But I cannot figure where is the error.

If I try to open the database there are many elements for the passed parameters but strangely doesn't find anything.

NB

*language* is a static value that depends by the device language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten the SQL wildcards...

This:

```
WHERE column = "John"
```

Is the same as:

```
WHERE column LIKE "John"
```

You want to incorporate `%` and `_` wildcards to create a clause like:

```
WHERE column LIKE "%John%"
```

---

Also you should take advantage of SQLite parametrization and protect yourself from [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks:

```
c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM dbtable " + 
        "WHERE Uso LIKE ? AND Eta LIKE ? AND Language LIKE ? ORDER BY Name",
        new String[] { "%" + uso + "%", 
                       "%" + eta + "%", 
                       "%" + language + "%" });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm not sure to have understood the right syntax.

Could you give me a sample for the first if block in getData()? (Eta, Name etc. are columns)

Comment: I updated my answer with a larger example. I used a fair amount of whitespace to help the new aspects jump out at you, feel free to use more.

Comment: ops... something is gone wrong... with this code the Cursor returns all entries of dtable :(

Comment: Post the code that you are using in your question and an example of `uso`, `eta`, `category`, and `language`.

Comment: I have edited the question adding the new full getData method... uso eta and category are non null String passed to the method, language is a static String of the class that depends by the device language

Comment: Where do `uso`, `eta`, and `category` come from? If they are EditText values they will never be `null`, but they might be _empty_ (i.e. `if(class.equals("")`).

Comment: for some reason seems that the error is caused from null values of the passed String. Thanks again. Now I'll try to fix the cause of the null String (the String are passed but strangely became null in some way).